# Switching the ordinate and abscissa causes problem in `ParametricPlot`

Tags: plotting, functions

I have a function that plots properly in `PolarPlot`, but I'd like to plot it in `ParametricPlot` and then switch the y and x values, or ordinate and abscissa.  It doesn't work for my function, but I'm not sure if it's just my function or some other subtle problem:

```
r[phi_] := (6*(Cos[phi]^5)/(2*Pi))^0.5;
PolarPlot[r[phi], {phi, 0, Pi}]
new[x_] := CoordinateTransform["Polar" -> "Cartesian", {Re[r[x]], x}];
ParametricPlot[{new[x], x}, {x, 0, Pi}]
ParametricPlot[{x, new[x]}, {x, 0, Pi}]
```

Generates:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The final plot doesn't contain anything, and no errors or warnings are output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `new[x]` returns an ordered pair, which you're then placing in a list to make a new ordered pair.  Try this instead:

```
ParametricPlot[new[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
ParametricPlot[Reverse@new[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know why `{new[x], x}` worked in the first place, but I don't actually care now...

Comment: It worked because your list effectively requested two parametric plots (new[x] and x), though the second parametric plot was underspecified and thus ignored by MMA.